# How to enforce a definite timeout in perl?

Tags: perl, timeout, lwp-useragent

I am using LWP to download content from web pages, and I would like to limit the amount of time it waits for a page.

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->timeout(10);
$ua->env_proxy;
$response = $ua->get("http://XML File");
$content = $response->decoded_content;
```

The problem is that the server will occasionally deadlock (we're trying to figure out why) and the request will never succeed. Since the server thinks it is live, it keeps the socket connection open thus LWP::UserAgent's timeout value does us no good what-so-ever. What is the best way to enforce an absolute timeout on a request?

Whenever the timeout reaches its limit, it just dies and I can't continue on with the script! 
This whole script is in a loop, where it has to fetch XML files sequentially.
I'd really like to handle this timeout properly and make the script continue to next address. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [True timeout on LWP::UserAgent request method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73308/true-timeout-on-lwpuseragent-request-method)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've faced a similar issue before in https://stackoverflow.com/a/10318268/1331451.

What you need to do is add a `$SIG{ALRM}` handler and use [`alarm`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm.html) to call it. You set the `alarm` before you do the call and cancel it directly afterwards. Then you can look at the HTTP::Result you get back.

The alarm will trigger the signal, and Perl will call the signal handler. In it, you can either do stuff directly and `die` or just `die`. The `eval` is for the `die` no to break the whole program. If the signal handler is called, the `alarm` is reset automatically.

You could also add different `die` messages to the handler and differentiate later on with `$@` like @larsen said in his answer.

Here's an example:

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $req = HTTP::Request->new;
my $res;
eval {
  # custom timeout (strace shows EAGAIN)
  # see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10318268/1331451
  local $SIG{ALRM} = sub {
    # This is where it dies
    die "Timeout occured...";
  }; # NB: \n required
  alarm 10;
  $res = $ua->request($req);
  alarm 0;
};
if ($res && $res->is_success) {
  # the result was a success
}
```

- [perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html) for signals.

Comment: This looks awesome, but doesn't work quite as expected for me.  Posted a new question to discuss it: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35614328/251589

Comment: FYI: I copy/pasted your answer to the duplicate questions here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/35614804/251589 and here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35614858/251589 if you want to post an answer there, leave me a comment and I will delete my answers.  You deserve the rep.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can use an `eval` block if you want to trap and control sections of code that may die.

```
while( … ) { # this is your main loop
    eval {
        # here the code that can die
    };
    if ($@) {
        # if something goes wrong, the special variable $@ 
        # contains the error message (as a string or as a blessed reference,
        # it depends on how the invoked code threats the exception.
    }
}
```

You can find further info in the documentation for [the eval function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html)