# Perl: Using alarms with Post request produces odd behaviour

Tags: perl, alarm, lwp, lwp-useragent

## Initial Question

I am trying use Perl to make a POST to a remote server.  I am using an alarm to set a hard timeout.  When the alarm triggers, I am getting what I would consider to be strange behaviour.

This is the code:

```
eval {  

    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub {
        die("Foobar");
    };
    alarm 25;


    my $userAgent = new LWP::UserAgent( keep_alive => 1 );
    $answer = $userAgent->post( ... );

    # During a timeout, I expect that this code will not run.  However,
    # it does and it prints "Foobar".
    $m = $answer->message();
    print $m;
    alarm 0;

};
alarm 0;        
print "Done";
```

Put a sleep (or breakpoint) on server, so it will not respond and so that the alarm will trigger.  When the alarm triggers, this will be printed:

```
Foobar
Done
```

My expectation was that this *should* print:

```
Done
```

Key questions:

- Why is this happening?  Am I using some kind of anti-pattern?  Is using alarms, not a good idea, because underlying libraries may use them as well, and they may conflict?
- What is the right way to solve this problem?

---

## Appendix 1 - I know there is another method...

I know that I should be using:

```
$userAgent->timeout( ... );
```

And actually, I am.  However, I would like to set a hard timeout as well, so that I can ensure that at most I will spend 25 seconds waiting on the request.  Since the timeout associated with `$userAgent->timeout( ... );` is reset each time the client gets something back from the server, it is not reliable enough.

---

## Appendix 2 - Environment Info

@bolav mentioned that on his system, he could not reproduce the issue, I guess that it is *possible* that it is System dependant.

OS:

```
cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
```

Perl Version:

```
This is perl, v5.6.1 built for i686-linux
```

---

## Appendix 3 - Answers on SO suggesting to use this method

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/15900249/251589

Comment: Your code only prints `Done` on my system, so it behaves as you expect. Are you sure you are not printing `$@ in your code? If not post more information about your system.

Comment: @bolav - I thought that I must be using `$@` initially as well.  I posted additional system info.

Comment: Wait, the default perl on RHEL 6 is 5.10.1. Why are you using 5.6.1? (ancient!)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot - Legacy code.

Comment: But maybe "Legacy code" is the answer to this question.  I primarily posted this question to see if I was doing something obviously wrong.